# Call a controller action in asp.net web API periodically

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I made a controller action in my asp.net web API MVC 4 and since its running was long i cached its output for 5 mins. Then made a .NET client to consume this API. Now i want that before cache expires action should be called again automatically in web API. So that every time its the cached output that the client gets. How to do that?
Is it possible to call a controller action from web API itself so that it gets cached every time or i would have to do it in ASP.NET client? 
here is the action from web api. To cache result on server i am using  `Strathweb.CacheOutput 0.5.0` package

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 300, ServerTimeSpan = 300)]
    public HttpResponseMessage givedisabledusers()
    {

        var result = dbh.givedisabledusers();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such mechanism where the output cache refreshes itself automatically after expiration. One solution would be to a create a worker process or background job that automatically 'pings' the API endpoint after a certain duration (in your case, perhaps every 4.5 minutes instead of 5 to allow for the db call/processing of `givedisabledusers()`).

Comment: yeah i want to do the same. This worker process will be in API,client or it will be a separate service? Can you please be more specific.

Comment: It won't be in the API - it will be in a separate app/service. There are many options: 1.) you could write a small console app that hits the API endpoint(s) and run this as a scheduled job. 2.) you could write a background service that periodically pings the endpoints.